# Limit $\sin(x)\cdot \ln(\cos(x))$ as $x\to \pi/2$

Tags: limits

I just did a question on a test, that I unfortunately know now that I was unable to do correctly. For me the real bothersome part is not that I didn't do it correctly, but more that I don't understand how to do it.

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2} \sin(x)\cdot \ln(\cos(x))$$

The question asked us to find it from both the left and the right. I looked it up on wolfrm alpha, which reference the power rule of limits, which we haven't learned so I don't imagine we were suppose to come to our conclusion that way. Either way though, evaluating the limit as is, I always get $1 \cdot{-\infty}$. We have learned that this is undefined though, so I am confused as to how the evaluation works. It seems from time to time people just do the multiplication and say $-\infty$ is the result.

My questions are as follows then:

- How can I go about understanding how this limit is evaluated?
- How would I be able to see that the limit only exists from the left without a visual aid?
- Since the limit only exists from the left, why is it possible to use it in an improper integral like:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\cdot \ln(\cos(x))\, dx$$

Comment: Both of you are correct. I have updated the question title to reflect the question.

Comment: A limit in the form $1\cdot(-\infty)$ is not “undefined”. It's just $-\infty$.

Comment: Can you expand on why that is? Aren't operations on infinity undefined?

Comment: @egreg I wonder, could you actually define $-\infty$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations on infinity are undefined, but when you are in a situation like
$$
\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=l,\qquad \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\infty
$$
with $l>0$ (and finite), then you can surely say that
$$
\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty
$$
Fix $M>0$; by hypothesis you can find

1. $\delta_1>0$ such that, for $0<|x-c|<\delta_1$, $g(x)>2M/l$
2. $\delta_2>0$ such that, for $0<|x-c|<\delta_2$, $f(x)>l/2$

Therefore, for $0<|x-c|<\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, we have
$$
f(x)g(x)>\frac{2M}{l}\frac{l}{2}=M
$$

Adapt to the cases $l<0$ and $-\infty$ and to the case of one-sided limits.

---

Of course your limit can only be taken “from the left”, where $\cos x>0$. It depends on conventions whether you can talk about
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\sin x\ln\cos x
$$
or just about
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\sin x\ln\cos x
$$
(In my convention, I use the first notation.)

In any case, your improper integral can be written
$$
\lim_{a\to\pi/2^-}\int_0^a\sin x\ln\cos x\,dx
$$
and the function under the integral sign is defined in all intervals of the form $[0,a]$, for $0<a<\pi/2$. So it makes sense to ask about its convergence.

Comment: Why 2M/l and l/2? What do you mean adapt the cases for l < 0?

Comment: @byteofthat That's just for “bookkeeping”: a standard trick like the infamous $\varepsilon/2$ so that the final inequality has $M$. It's easy to do similarly for the cases $l<0$ or $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=-\infty$ (and also when $c=\pm\infty$, too). Also the cases $l=\pm\infty$ can be dealt with similarly (but they're easier).

Comment: Hmm, and where in your explanation can we see that M will imply infinity?

Comment: @byteofthat Definition of infinite limit?

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow. Can you elaborate on what your $\delta$ values represent? Hopefully I can get a better idea of what your cases mean then.

Comment: @byteofthat Just spell out the definition of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Alright, I think I will need to take some time to fully understand that. Finally, can you touch on why I can use the integral like so? We have been taught that if the limit is not the same from both sides than it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to\pi/2$ from the left, $\cos x$ goes downward to $0$, so $\ln\cos x$ goes downward to $-\infty$.  But as $x\to\pi/2$ from the right, you'd be taking the logarithm of a negative number, and that is undefined.

You need to recall from trigonometry that $\cos x>0$ immediately to the left of $\pi/2$ and $\cos x<0$ immediately to the right of $\pi/2$.

Confusing language exists: One says that as $x\uparrow\pi/2$, then $\cos x$ "diverges" to $-\infty$ rather than $\cos x$ "converges" to $-\infty$, and that the limit does not exist, and that the limit is $-\infty$.  To say that the limit exists is often taken to mean the limit is a real number and not one of $\pm\infty$.  Theorems assert things like the limit of $f+g$ is the limit of $f$ plus the limit of $g$ provided both limits "exist", but the theorem does not apply if either limit is one of $\pm\infty$, since then the limit "does not exist".

However, as $x\downarrow\pi/2$, nothing exists whose limit is taken; it's not just the limit that is said not to exist; it's the values of the function.

The integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}$ does not depend on what happens when $x>\pi/2$, but only on what happens when $0<x<\pi/2$.